# How can pip be installed locally for use with Python 2.7?

Tags: python, pip, local, easy-install

I want to install `pip` locally together with a local install of Python 2.7. I am using an EPEL6 system on which I am not root. I have `easy_install` available on the system by default (no `pip` or `virtualenv` to begin with).

I have managed to install pip and Python 2.7, but I don't know how to proceed to get `pip` working with the Python 2.7 install (as opposed to Python 2.6).

```
cd
mkdir local_test
cd local_test

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6/Python-2.6.tgz
tar -xvf Python-2.6.tgz
cd Python-2.6
./configure --prefix=/home/user/local_test
make
make install
cd ..
rm -rf Python-2.6
rm Python-2.6.tgz

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.12/Python-2.7.12.tgz
tar -xvf Python-2.7.12.tgz
cd Python-2.7.12
./configure --prefix=/home/user/local_test
make
make install
cd ..
rm -rf Python-2.7.12
rm Python-2.7.12.tgz

export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/local_test/lib/python2.6/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}

easy_install --prefix=~/local_test pip

export PATH=/home/user/local_test/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) to manage your entire Python environment.  This way, you can avoid doing any `configure`/`make` steps, and it will come with `pip` by default.  It replaces the need for `virtualenv`, and can be easily installed in your home directory.